# How can I change all // comments into /* */ comments in C language?

Tags: python, c, bash, awk, formatting

I have some c source files. Inside, there is multiple comments with '//' style and others with '/* */' style.

I want to change all of them to /* */ to have more uniformity inside my code and also to respect the standard column width.

How can I change all this comments automatically ?

Thank you for reading !

---

Edit: I just realize that I didn't explain something important. I need to change my comments to make them compatible with C89. The rest of the coding style is already compatible. Just I don't want to delete all comment or to edit all of them manually. And I think it is also an interesting question.

Comment: It's generally impossible without writing a parser for C. If you have some small subset of the language and dont have to deal with things like `printf("foo // bar\n")` needing to remain unchanged then it may be possible but you'd need to define that subset and provide a comprehensive example of a program written in that subset. You might want to google "C beautifier" to see if any of them do what you want.

Comment: There exists some "beautifier" tools that can do that for you. Good editors or IDE's could also do this for you.

Comment: *I have some c source files.* what is total number of lines of codes for them?

Comment: IMO, you want to go the other way around. Convert all K&R to ANSI. My perl script for doing so [in either direction] is ~200 lines

Comment: I would use something like `sed 's;//\(.*\);/*\1 */;`, but I would have to go back and make sure it didn't convert based on a `//` it happened to find that was in a string literal.  (If there was a relatively small number of files, I might use query-replace-regexp in emacs — but then, I'm an emacs user.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a one line black magic awk/bash or python that can help me solve this problem without spending hours changing it manually ?

Unsure, but a C program to do it (most of the time) is not too hard to code and a fun project.

Most code can be parsed 1 `char` at a time into a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Example:_coin-operated_turnstile) keeping track of which of 5 states processing is in: in_code, in_slash_star_comment, in_slash_slash_comment, in_double_quote, in_single_quote.
Then emit the same output unless modified per being in the in_slash_slash_comment.

Comment: Ha! but don't forget things can get funky, `"this is a valid \"/* string */\*!" contains no comments, so if you're going character-based, you'll need to have escape-sequence handling, too.

Comment: (I like this answer. It's very "hands-on, don't hesitate, you might learn something")

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, escape sequences add to the fun.  Pedantic: Don't forget [trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C).  OTOH, let us forget about trigraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, that would be the job of a code formatter, and you'd need to at least be able to lex C, which is not really something you want to implement in a shell script or awk program.

Instead, for example, `clang-format` has plenty options to adjust how your comments look, and should be pretty much available on any desktop OS.

Note that using `//` for one-line comments is actually fine, imho, and you don't gain anything by using the `/*  */` syntax for such.

Comment: Going from `// .. eol` to `/* .... */` has a singular gain: allowing compiling with an old C89 - not that the rest of code won't also need changes.

Comment: That's true, but if the code base compiled before, that's not gonna change.

Comment: I've used such transformations to port code from C99 (on one machine/compiler) to C89 (on another machine/compiler), so its a first time compile on the new target.

Comment: With your answers I realize this is a much more complicated issue that what I used to think.

Comment: But with a C lexer (like using clang) it should be possible,  isn't it ? Or do I misinterpret your answer ?